# How to update display of google map based on new lat, lon - onchange trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Working on the script that will update display of map once I enter the postcode (onchange trigger).

Note that map is initialized already with default lat lon values.

So far script finds lat and lon based on entered postcode (this works fine) and here comes the part i'm stuck on. I would like to update display of the map based on these new lat/lon values. So i try to initilize new map, but that seem to not work at all.

What should i do?

My code so far:

HTML

```
<input name='drpostcode' id='drpostcode'type="text" placeholder="Postcode"  onchange="find_Drlatlon();"/>
<input name="lat1" type="hidden" id="lat1">
<input name="lon1" type="hidden" id="lon1">

<div id="map"></div>
```

JS

```
function find_Drlatlon() {

function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
}
        var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder1.geocode({
            address: $("#drpostcode").val() + ", UK"
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var result = results[0];
                $("#lat1").val(roundNumber(result.geometry.location.lat(), 6));
                $("#lon1").val(roundNumber(result.geometry.location.lng(), 6));
                var lat1 = document.driverregform.lat1.value;
                var lon1 = document.driverregform.lon1.value;
                console.log(lat1);
                console.log(lon1);

  var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1); 
  console.log(myLatLng);             

  var citymap = {
    driverslocation: {
      center: {myLatLng}
    }
  };
    console.log(citymap);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
      zoom: 8,
      center: {myLatLng},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });


    for (var city in citymap) {
      var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: 30000
      });
    }


            } else {}
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a LatLng object you can use it like so:

`map.setCenter(position);`

in your case in the result callback:

`map.setCenter(result.geometry.location);`

This will center the map on that location. 
You can get a LatLng object from values via

`new google.maps.LatLng(36.1694233,-115.1407836)`

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to implement it in the code i have so far.... if i run initMap() as a standalone function works perfectly. Is just seem to be doing nothing on onchange trigger

Comment: it looks to me that function initMap() is not triggered, any advice?

Comment: ok, sorted, there was no call for initMap(), works as expected

Comment: to fast i was testing it on acutall hardcoded lat lon.  now i have issue with passing the lat lon values to the map .... InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: do you have some updated code? The code goes in the callback body after you set the result var,  so after `var result = results[0];`. Also: right now you're setting the value of the input fields (which is useful I guess, if you're posting the form at a later time) but then you retrieve the value from the inputs you just set which makes no sense to me.

Comment: code updeted, this is what i have now. if i hardcode the lat lon, works as expected, otherwise as i mention before

Answer (score 0):

Brackets around myLatLon variable in the map, this was the issue, working code below.

```
function find_Drlatlon() {

function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
}
        var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder1.geocode({
            address: $("#drpostcode").val() + ", UK"
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (results[0]) {
                var result = results[0];
                $("#lat1").val(roundNumber(result.geometry.location.lat(), 6));
                $("#lon1").val(roundNumber(result.geometry.location.lng(), 6));
                var lat1 = document.driverregform.lat1.value;
                var lon1 = document.driverregform.lon1.value;
                console.log(lat1);
                console.log(lon1);

  var myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lon1); 
  console.log(myLatLng);             

  var citymap = {
    driverslocation: {
      center: myLatLng
    }
  };
    console.log(citymap);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });


    for (var city in citymap) {
      var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: 30000
      });
    }


            } else {}
        });
};
```